# Taxonomy url change to friendly url

Tags: wordpress, url, taxonomy

Hi my taxonomy url is like :

`/voitures/?make=bmw`

and want to change it to a friendly url with a function or with htaccess to :

`/voitures/make/bmw`

Comment: Have you try this https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen ?

Comment: @purvik7373 Im using a plugin for creating taxonomies there is no parameteres to change taxonomy url